# How to access All tenant table data at once

Tags: laravel, multi-tenant, laravel-9

Suppose I have `tenant_1` and `tenant_2`

```
## Tenant 1
- Users
  - Test User 1
  - Test User 2
```

```
## Tenant 2
- Users
  - Test User 3
  - Test User 4
```

What I Want is to show all the users at once for admin view

Output :

```
- Users
  - Test User 1
  - Test User 2
  - Test User 3
  - Test User 4
```

In this case I've 2 tenant But incase i've 3 tenants then i want the users from users table of all 3 tenant databases
Is any feasible solution to achieve the above scenario?

Laravel Version: 9.37.0

Spatie Multi tenancy : https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-multitenancy/v2/introduction

I've Also Opened Disscussion after I didn't got any Solution.

https://github.com/spatie/laravel-multitenancy/discussions/410

Any help will be Usefull.

Comment: I'm guessing each tenant is based on a database scheme or connection. But i think you need to specify where these different data sources are.

Comment: @mrhn I've 2 database connection only in database.php . 1 is for tenant no matter how many database i create for tenant connection.

Comment: What does tenant 1 vs tenant 2 tables differ from each other? that is not clear in your question.

Comment: I hope you know the tenant usage. @mrhn

Answer (score 0):

Fetch each users by their tenant and put them in the array

Example:

```
$tenants  = Tenant::all();
Foreach($tenants as $tenant){
  $users[] = User::useConnection($tenant->getConnection())->get(); 
}
```

Comment: In this way, I'll get all the users but the connection will be changed at the end of for each and I can't do this for all modules. But thanks

Comment: Did you find another solution?